# How are YUI ids generated?

Tags: html, css, yui, squarespace

I'm working with a squarespace site that is using YUI. Every time the page refreshes, different YUI ids will be generated. This is cool, but someone on my team has been fudging up and using the ids for styling purposes in a myriad of stylesheets. I know that this won't effect the actual site because the ids will be generated differently every time, but I want to understand potential risk.
Is there a chance that the same YUI id will ever be generated twice?
How are they being generated?
I'm thinking that if they're heavily based on date/time, the risk is close to none and I don't have to be really concerned about hunting down all these worthless stylings that call on the YUI ids.

Also I'm just plain ol' curious.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just incrementing a timestamp..
You should not get twice the same ids when loading the page different times.

The code using http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/files/yui_js_yui.js.html#1455

Comment: It's using a counter, but the `this.Env._guidp` prefix is a timestamp. See https://github.com/yui/yui3/blob/master/src/yui/js/yui.js#L445-L446